# how to catch exception if js bundle is corrupt in react native

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, exception

I have a brownfield android app and I am building a custom solution to update js bundle from a server where I will update the latest bundle similar to codepush.
There is edge case I want to cover when I have uploaded a corrupted bundle in that case app will crash. I want to catch that app crashing and so that I can revert back to my previous working bundle.
I have encountered an issue where my app crashes with the following exception: "com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly". I want to catch this exception globally in my app.

I have tried overriding `JSBundleLoader` in  `ReactInstanceManager`
similar to this and I was able to catch error, but when there is no error it wasn't loading the view

```js
val reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
    .setApplication(application)
    .setCurrentActivity(activity)
    .setJSMainModulePath(jsBundlePath)
    .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
    .setJSBundleLoader(MyJSBundleLoader())
    .build()
```

I also have tried using DefaultJSExceptionHandler to catch the exception, but I am not sure how to implement it correctly. I have also looked into using ReactCxxErrorHandler and setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler on the React Native thread, but I am not sure how to trigger a native code when there is an error in React Native.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to catch this exception globally in my Android React Native app using DefaultJSExceptionHandler? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.
I want to catch this exception in native side using java/kotlin without depending on js side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to catch corrupt js bundle file and other errors related to js bundle by overriding `createReactInstanceManager`  method from `ReactNativeHost` class.

```
override fun createReactInstanceManager(): ReactInstanceManager? {
            ReactMarker.logMarker(ReactMarkerConstants.BUILD_REACT_INSTANCE_MANAGER_START)
            val delegates = arrayOf<JSBundleLoader>(
                JSBundleLoader.createAssetLoader(
                    application.applicationContext, this.getJSBundleFile(), false /* Asynchronous */),
            )
            val builder = ReactInstanceManager.builder().setApplication(application)
                .setJSMainModulePath(this.jsMainModuleName)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(this.useDeveloperSupport)
                .setDevSupportManagerFactory(this.devSupportManagerFactory)
                .setRequireActivity(this.shouldRequireActivity)
                .setSurfaceDelegateFactory(this.surfaceDelegateFactory)
                .setLazyViewManagersEnabled(this.lazyViewManagersEnabled)
                .setRedBoxHandler(this.redBoxHandler)
                .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(this.javaScriptExecutorFactory)
                .setUIImplementationProvider(this.uiImplementationProvider)
                .setJSIModulesPackage(this.jsiModulePackage).setInitialLifecycleState(
                    LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE
                )
                .setJSExceptionHandler{e->
                    run {
                        //this is where you want to use the catched error
                        println("handleException $e")
                        val defaultJSExceptionHandler = DefaultJSExceptionHandler()
                        defaultJSExceptionHandler.handleException(e)
                    }
                }
                .setReactPackageTurboModuleManagerDelegateBuilder(this.reactPackageTurboModuleManagerDelegateBuilder)
            val var2: Iterator<*> = this.packages.iterator()

            while (var2.hasNext()) {
                val reactPackage = var2.next() as ReactPackage
                builder.addPackage(reactPackage)
            }

            val jsBundleFile = this.jsBundleFile
            if (jsBundleFile != null) {
                builder.setJSBundleFile(jsBundleFile)
            } else {
                builder.setBundleAssetName(Assertions.assertNotNull(this.bundleAssetName))
            }

            val reactInstanceManager = builder.build()
            ReactMarker.logMarker(ReactMarkerConstants.BUILD_REACT_INSTANCE_MANAGER_END)
            return reactInstanceManager
            }
```